# Angular2 navbar-subnavbar , show subnav menu after check the navbar link

Tags: angular

in subnav i want to create a component if its this (/company) link, show me subMenus buttons.

navbar component:

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit 

{
  navbar = [

    {
      name: 'Company',
      link: '/company',
      subMenu: [
        { name: 'test1', link: '/test1'},
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'About',
      link: '/about',
      subMenu: [
        { name: 'test2', link: '/test2'},
      ]
    },
```

Comment: Was the answer helpful???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code. In which your navbar component will contain the below markup

```
<div *ngFor="let menu in navbar" >
    <a [routerLink]="['menu.link']">{{menu.name}} </a>
    <sub-menu [menus]="menu.subMenu"> </sub-menu>
</div>
```

Your sub-menu component will have the below code

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'sub-menu',
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="let menu of menus"> 
            <a [routerLink]="['menu.link']">{{menu.name}} </a>
        </div>
    `
})
export class StepComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() menus: any[] = [];
    constructor() { 
        ....
    }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Comment: if this was helpful please mark as answer and upvote. Happy to help you. :)